# How can i copy all the files in a folder and change the name in the same directory?

Tags: bash

i am having trouble trying to copy all the numbered files in a directory and change their names in the same directory but with same number, i am trying to do this:

```
cp rj1.text mike1.text
cp rj2.text mike2.text
cp rj3.text mike3.text
cp rj4.text mike4.text
cp rj5.text mike5.text
cp rj6.text mike6.text
```

this is the code i tried using

`cp /home/ryan/Desktop/rj/"rj*.text" /home/ryan/Desktop/rj/"mike*.text"`

Answer (score 2):

Since this is tagged `[bash]` you can use a simple *parameter expansion with substring replacement* to loop over the files replacing `"rj"` with `"mike"` as you copy each file.

For example You can do:

```sh
for f in *; do 
  cp "$f" "${f/rj/mike}"
done
```

(**note:** if you have more than just the `"rj"` files in the directory, you can replace the `*` glob with `rj[[:digit:]].text` to only match files with `"rj"` followed by a single-digit and the `.text`. Or, to just match digits `1-6`, you can use `rj[123456].txt` or `rj{1..6}.txt`, up to you. The `[123456]` will work with all POSIX shells, the brace-expansion `{1..6}` is bash only)

**Example Use/Output**

Change to an empty directory and create the six file with `"rj"` in the name:

```sh
touch rj{1..6}.text
```

Now copy and change the name using the command above. The result you are wanting is now in the directory with both the `"rj"` and `"mike"` copies of the files, e.g.

```
$ tree
.
├── mike1.text
├── mike2.text
├── mike3.text
├── mike4.text
├── mike5.text
├── mike6.text
├── rj1.text
├── rj2.text
├── rj3.text
├── rj4.text
├── rj5.text
└── rj6.text
```

(**note:** to move the files from `"rj"` to `"mike"` removing the `"rj"` files, just use the `mv` command instead of `cp`)

Comment: `for f in *; do` will catch all files, including `foo.bar`, which will cause a `cp` error when executing `cp "$f" "${f/rj/mike}"`. `shopt -s extglob nullglob; for f in rj+([0-9]).text; do ...` would probably be safer. Also please note that `rj[123456].txt` and `rj{1..6}.txt` are not the same, they will produce different results. With `nullglob` enabled `rj[123456].txt` will expand to only the existing matching files (or the null string if there are none) while `rj{1..6}.txt` will expand as the 6 names, even if they don't exist.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet - if you note, I included explanation on how to tighten the glob should more than just the files you are looking for reside in the current directory in the **note:** directly below it.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, and it's perfect, but still, I think that starting with a safer solution where the glob is compatible with the pattern substitution would be preferable. I think also that `nullglob` would be even safer to avoid `cp * *` or `cp rj[[:digit:]].text mike[[:digit:]].text`. And "_Or, to just match digits 1-6, you can use `rj[123456].txt` or `rj{1..6}.txt`, up to you_" is a bit misleading, I think, because the former is affected by the pathname expansion while the latter is not and can produce non-existing file names. But this last point is probably of less importance.

Comment: Yes, point made. If there are gaps in the numeric range in either case, you can check for existence with `[ -f "$f" ]` (or `[ -s "$f" ]` for non-empty files). However, without the test, you can simply rely on `cp` failing for the non-existent file. Always more that can be added to cover corner-cases not present in the example data.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of a multi-step process:

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
cp ../rj*.text ./
rename rj mike *.text
cp ./* ..
cd ..
rm -rf tmp
```

Comment: thanks for responding, do you know a way that i can do this by using absolute paths instead of cd so i can add into my bash script?

Comment: @ryanpositiveguy what do you mean by "using absolute paths instead of cd"? cd is just a utility to **c**hange the current **d**irectory. You can use absolute or relative paths with any utility.

Comment: oh okay, yes so how would i do that code using a absolute path?

Comment: You... replace the relative path with an absolute path? Anyways: There is no need to use an absolute path in a script. `cd` works fine in a script. In your case you simply add `cd /home/ryan/Desktop/rj/` to the beginning of the commands.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your wildcard `*` would not be expanded, because it is between single quotes and `cp` itself (like most commands) does not understand wildcards.

One possibility to do this in bash would be to shell out to zsh for this, because zsh hat the command `zmv` which does understand wildcards:

```
zsh -c "autoload zmv; zmv -Cv 'rj(*).txt' "'mike $1.txt'
```

The `autoload` is necessary, since `zmv` is not available in zsh automatically. The `$1` refers to the expression between parenthesis.

If you need such a "copy with rename" more often, I would find it more sensible to create a separate script (say: `copy_ren`) for this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/env zsh
autoload zmv
zmv -Cv $1 $2
```

and then call it (provided it is executable and in your PATH) by

```
copy_ren 'rj(*).txt' 'mike$1.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt:

```
cp /home/ryan/Desktop/rj/"rj*.text" /home/ryan/Desktop/rj/"mike*.text"
```

cannot work for at least two reasons:

- By quoting the glob patterns (`"rj*.text"` and `"mike*.text"`) you prevent their expansion to the matching file names. Bash will really try to copy a file literally named `/home/ryan/Desktop/rj/rj*.text` to a file literally named `/home/ryan/Desktop/rj/mike*.text`.
- Even if you do not quote the patterns they will expand as the list of all matching file names... except if there is none, in which case the pattern expands as itself by default. In your case, if you have the 6 files you listed and no `mike` files, after expansion by the shell the command will become (directory names removed for better readability):

  ```sh
  cp rj1.text rj2.text rj3.text rj4.text rj5.text rj6.text mike*.text
  ```

  and it will fail because copying more than one file is allowed only if the destination is a directory and you don't have a directory named `mike*.text`.

So you need a loop to copy the files individually. If your `rj` files can have any number, including with more than one digit, they can be matched exactly with the `extglob` bash option:

```sh
/home/ryan/Desktop/rj/rj+([0-9]).text
```

matches any file named `/home/ryan/Desktop/rj/rjN.text` where `N` is a number with one or more digits.

I suggest to also enable the `nullglob` option such that the pattern expands to the null string if no files match. Finally, a simple pattern substitution can produce the destination name:

```sh
shopt -s extglob nullglob
dir="/home/ryan/Desktop/rj/"
for file in "${dir}"rj+([0-9]).text; do
  cp "$file" "${file/${dir}rj/${dir}mike}"
done
```